# WXPython Maximize Frame Disable Resizing

Tags: wxpython, kde-plasma

I am using Python 2.7.6 and wxPython 2.8.12.1 on Linux Mint 17.1 KDE Desktop 4.14.2. I am trying to develop an application in which the window will start maximized and there will be no maximize box or resize box. In other words users will not be able to resize the window. Here is my code.

```
import wx

class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = (wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.MAXIMIZE) & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.RESIZE_BOX|wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = wx.App(0)
    f = Frame1(None, -1, "No Resize")
    a.MainLoop()
```

On KDE desktop, I do not get the maximized window. What is it I am missing here?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RESIZE_BOX is not a valid style, after I remove that and add MINIZE_BOX to the styles to be removed it works for me on Win8 and Mint17 with Phoenix and with wxPython 2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode):

```
import wx

class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = (wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.MAXIMIZE) & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = wx.App(0)
    f = Frame1(None, -1, "No Resize")
    a.MainLoop(
```

)

Comment: No change. Same no-maximized window. May be it's related to KDE desktop, I am not sure. Are you on KDE?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some code on Kubuntu and came up with this:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        style = wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test', style=style)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Close")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)

        self.Show()
        self.Maximize(True)

    def onClose(self, event):
        self.Close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The key was calling `ShowFullScreen` to get it to maximize. I also edited the style flags slightly. You might also find the following articles helpful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/12/wxpython-making-your-frame-maximize-or-full-screen/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/11/06/wxpython-101-using-frame-styles/

Comment: It shows full screen, covering everything. No title, no close box. Also I need the minimize box and the close box. I don't need the maximize/resize box only.
Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm...Yeah, I should have used `self.Maximize` and fixed the style flag set. I updated the answer, although this isn't quite working on my Kubuntu VM yet